# Trace the logs based on MessageID at server side in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, trace, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb4.7.0. Wish to trace the logs at server side.for this i have created a simple service in which I have put log at inSequence,sequence1,sequence2 and outSequence.My output is look like :

```
[2015-02-18 11:08:10,937]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/LogDetection, MessageID: urn:uuid:cbd2c3df-f717-4a44-92e4-68ff12038d2a, Direction: request, partybranchid in INSEQUENCE OF MAIN PROXY = -1, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><partybranchid>-1</partybranchid></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-02-18 11:08:10,947]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:a11ee439-65b0-4875-bb82-132267455fb2, Direction: response, Log in = SEQUENCE1, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns4:binary xmlns:axis2ns4="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"></axis2ns4:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-02-18 11:08:10,955]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:ad3a016f-3e2c-49bf-bdb0-a40c7b91e25e, Direction: response, Log in = SEQUENCE2, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns5:binary xmlns:axis2ns5="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"></axis2ns5:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-02-18 11:08:10,963]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:7a7b7f2d-3713-440d-b95c-583901848ec0, Direction: response, partybranchid in OUTSEQUENCE OF MAIN PROXY = -1, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns6:binary xmlns:axis2ns6="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"></axis2ns6:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Above log shows me that my pointer started moving from inSequence to seq1 to seq2 to outSequence. Each log having it's unique MessageID but it seems different for each log in same service too. If i wish to trace logs then MessageID is best option as it is unique parameter. But if it is different then how can i trace it?